# jTDS / JDBC call Store Procedure, error… getMoreResults()

Tags: android, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

Here is code of my MS SQL Server Stored Procedure with have one input and one output parameter :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddItem] @numer nvarchar(50) , @ff int Output
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Category = @ff
    FROM [AWE_database].[dbo].[Items]
    WHERE Catalog_number=@numer     
END
```

And I try to run it on my phone ( using Android Studio). To connect with my database I use jtds-1.3.1 library.

```
try {

CallableStatement cs ;
              cs = this.connect.prepareCall("{call AddItem(?,?)}");
              cs.setString(1, c);
              cs.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

              int s = cs.getInt(2);

              cat = getString(s);

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
```

I get such error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Output parameters have not yet been processed. Call getMoreResults().
```

I searched the forum to find some sollution and tryed many examples but no one works. 
How shoudl I use `getMoreResults()` ? 
Or something other is wrong ? 
I could add that I run procedures with return many parameters and it works. 
But this procedure have also an input parameter.

I am a beginner in programming. Please Help